# Reusing SocketAsyncEventArgs at sendAsync couses infinite loop

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

i'm learning sockets and i have this program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace client
{
public class MyClient
{
    static ManualResetEvent _clientDonte = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static Socket _clientSocket;
    private SocketAsyncEventArgs _connectSocketEventArg;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelationTokenSource;

    public MyClient()
    {

    }

    public void Start(string address, uint port)
    {
        _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        IPEndPoint serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), (int)port);
        _connectSocketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

        _connectSocketEventArg.Completed += ConnectSocketEventArgCompleted;
        _connectSocketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = serverEP;
        _connectSocketEventArg.UserToken = _clientSocket;

        _clientSocket.ConnectAsync(_connectSocketEventArg);
        _clientDonte.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("DAJESZ KURWA, NAPISZ COS!");
        while (true)
        {
            SendFromConsole();
        }

    }

    private void SendFromConsole()
    {
        var message = Console.ReadLine();
        var buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        _connectSocketEventArg.SetBuffer(buff, 0, buff.Length);
        _clientSocket.SendAsync(_connectSocketEventArg);
    }

    private void ConnectSocketEventArgCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Connect:
                ProcessConnect(e);
                break;
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                ReceiveAsync(e);
                break;
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                SendAsync(e);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid operation completed");
        }
    }

    private void SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            Socket sock = e.UserToken as Socket;
            bool willRaiseEvent = sock.SendAsync(e);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                ReceiveAsync(e);

            }
        }

    }

    private void ReceiveAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SERVER>>: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Buffer));
            Socket sock = e.UserToken as Socket;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessConnect(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        _cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ProgressConnect, _cancelationTokenSource.Token);

        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(701);
            _cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Nawiazano polaczenie!");
            _clientDonte.Set();
        }
        else if (e.SocketError == SocketError.SocketError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nie udalo sie! nacisnij cos by wyjsc");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }

    private void ProgressConnect()
    {
        while (!_cancelationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            _cancelationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(700);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It is supposed to allow to write message, send it and wait for response asynchronously. Unfortunately when i send first message it's falling into infinite loop of sending. 
I have seen this [Reusing SocketAsyncEventArgs with ReceiveAsync results in infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366427/reusing-socketasynceventargs-with-receiveasync-results-in-infinite-loop) topic but it didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used this construction, but;

The infinite loop of sending might be, you never check if the bytes you are trying to send are sent. You might want to check if the `BytesTransferred` property is equal to the bytes you are trying to sent.

---

Also, you are blocking the current thread with the manual reset event.. Why aren't you using the non-async `Connect()`?

Comment: Before i was using some flags here: 
    bool willRaiseEvent = sock.SendAsync(e);
            if (willRaiseEvent)
            {
              isSent = true;

            }

and checking in condition before send it is not sent but it was not working as well
ConnectAsync is working as well, i have no problem there.
How and why should i use manual reset event? Why SendAsync would not stop just after one send?

Comment: Because you're calling `SendAsync(e);` again when the `ConnectSocketEventArgCompleted` is called. so you're getting into a loop. I would use a different approach. Using the blocked Connect/Send and just using async for receiving. Makes it a lot easier.